# How to set limits of the primary and secondary axis in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there an easy way to set the limits of primary axis as `806.0 - 808.0` while limits for the secondary axis as `0 - 15`? tried to provide `limits = c(0,15)` in the `scaly_y_continuous` but that would take care of the secondary axis limits only.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
FakeData <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), 
                                  to= as.Date("2001-12-31"), 
                                  by="day"),
                       Elevation1 = runif(365, 806.8,807.8),
                       Elevation2 = runif(365, 806.2, 807.3),
                       FlowA = runif(365,8,15),
                       FlowB = runif(365,1,3))
#Scale factor
scalefactor <- max(FakeData$Elevation1, 
                   max(FakeData$Elevation2))/max(max(FakeData$FlowA),
                                                 max(FakeData$FlowB))

#Plot
ggplot(FakeData, aes(x = Date))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Elevation1,group=1,color='Elevation1'),show.legend = T)+
  geom_line(aes(y = Elevation2,group=1,color='Elevation2'),show.legend = T)+
  geom_line(aes(y = FlowA*scalefactor, color = 'FlowA'))+
  geom_line(aes(y = FlowB*scalefactor, color = 'FlowB'))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scalefactor, name = 'Flow A and Flow B'))
```

Comment: Where would that leave data that's not within the limits on your primary axis, but is within range on your secondary axis?

Comment: exactly what i am looking for- I want set the `limits` for the two `axis` based on their data range. the `primary axis` varies between `806 - 808` while `secondary axis` between `0-15`

Comment: @Greg any thoughts/suggestions to address the `y-scale` `limits`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing will work, but your scaling is not working effectively. If you want the axes to line up better, your scaling will need to result in a more similar location on the plot (the secondary axis is still using the catesian coordinates of the first axis). Limits won't work because the limits of your two axes are inherently the same (the top and bottom of the y axis). If your goal is to just keep the text for 806 - 808, but not actually change the limits or where your data are currently plotted, you could use `breaks` to do that. You can have a breaks argument for the primary y axis and for the secondary y axis.

Here is a simpler scaling version to get you started. You can work with it to get a better understanding of how the scaling is working and why yours might not be doing quite what you want. You may also need to add `breaks =` to your ggplot code.

```
#Plot
ggplot(FakeData, aes(x = Date))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Elevation1,group=1,color='Elevation1'),show.legend = T)+
  geom_line(aes(y = Elevation2,group=1,color='Elevation2'),show.legend = T)+
  geom_line(aes(y = (FlowA/5+806), color = 'FlowA'))+
  geom_line(aes(y = (FlowB/5+806), color = 'FlowB'))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(806,807,808),sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.-806)*5, name = 'Flow A and Flow B',breaks = c(0,5,10,15)))
```